# How does your company measure end to end experiences for their products?

Tags: usability, ux-field

At IBM we have a system that measures an offering's UX based on specific criteria. Does your company produce similar reports before a major release?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can expand on your question so that it is a little bit more than a YES or NO answer. And because I don't know if people are willing to share their own internal reports (even the structure if not the data), it would be good if you can highlight the exact problem you are trying to solve or answer you want to gather. IBM seems to have a pretty comprehensive design language and design system, so you would expect there to be a pretty solid way of measuring UX (although this is of course an assumption).

Comment: Yes, here at IBM we have a "design council" that measures ux based on certain quality dimensions. a few of them are discoverability, UX, IA, and visual design. This council then gives an offering a grade and how it can be improved. Im wondering if other companies do something similar? and how do they measure their products ux?

Comment: Are these dimension more qualitative or are they quantitative and benchmarked to internal/external standards? IA and visual design seem to be more difficult to assess compared to discoverability, and UX is pretty much the sum of everything I guess?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I suspect this is something that varies from organisation to organisation, and from product to product (hopefully not).

Generally if any UX processes are involved, hopefully there will be an assessment of the usability (if not the entire experience) of the product in the form of either task completion analysis (for a new product) or benchmark against existing baselines.

Alternatively, if the product is externally reviewed, then there will be some metrics or reports from the external source that can be gathered and analysed (e.g. traffic or review ratings).

**UPDATE** (based on additional comments):

Rather than measuring and benchmarking against an absolute value, one approach that you might be interested in is a method I developed for one of the companies that I worked at.

The process involves defining different types of experience that the product or service is aiming for (e.g. Usable, Useful, Engaging, Delightful) and then comparing that to the processes used to achieve the outcome (e.g. Research, Design, Prototype, Test).

So for a product that is designed to just be usable, the minimum process required might be to do some usability testing. For a product that needs to be delightful, more processes would be required.

Therefore, each product gets a check against the experience that it is aiming for and the processes used to achieve the outcome. The benchmark would be to provide the minimum amount of process required to achieve a particular outcome, and obviously the more you can do the better.